# Gradle Android -how to set manifest srcFile

Tags: android, gradle

in my Gradle build im not able to set the manifest path for a sourceset. Here is the block of code in question:

```
sourceSets{
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml' //im getting a error here
        main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res-other'
        betatest.java.srcDirs = ['src/qaInt/java']
        betatest.res.srcDirs = ['src/qaInt/res']
        betatest.assets.srcDirs = ['src/qaInt/assets']
    }
```

The error im getting is that there is no such method srcFile in manifest. How do i set the manifest path for a sourceSet ?

```
Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'srcFile()'
```

my gradle dependencies look like this:

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
}
```

im on android studio 2.0 preview 4 but same issue occurs on android studio 1.5

UPDATE: I just realized sourceSets closure is handling multiple things not just for betatest.  So what i really want is to change the bestatest flavor's androidmanifest. I want to set its path. So really , how do i set the path of the androidmanifest for a flavor ?

Comment: Please share your full build.gradle file the one that has the "android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    sourceSets {" settings

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you need to check/add that this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Is at the top of you app module `build.gradle` file, before the `android { }`.

The android stuff goes to a module (subdirectory) specific build.gradle, not the project-level that usually just configures repositories and so on

Please also share your **build.gradle** file the one that has this settings, to help you further

```
android { compileSdkVersion 19 buildToolsVersion "19.0.0" sourceSets {
```

Comment: im alreadying applying from that plugin.  The code runs fine and is a very complex app adroid app.  if i comment out that one line, everything runs.

Comment: does that mean that you have solved the issue ?